# Cypress not detecting some changes

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm currently writing the following Cypress test for a Angular(11) app:

```
it('should not work', function () {
  cy.get('#someInput').type('someValue');
  cy.contains('someButton').click();

  cy.contains('someText');
  cy.get('.someClass');

  cy.get('#some element that doest show up unless the window is scrolled.')
    .contains(
      'someText'
    )
    .find('a')
    .should('have.attr', 'href', 'someUrl');
});
```

The last element will always fail unless I scroll (manually/or automatic). I can add a `cy.wait(1000)` followed by a `cy.scrollTo(0, 750)` and then the test will pass. How does this work and why do I need the wait and scroll?

Comment: what do you see in the test window ?  May be some `ngIf` is not letting it render until it is not visible on screen. Hard to say with such limited info and code. Can you provide component code ?